# Parse char from int input in C

Tags: c, input

I am trying to display a matrix by taking input from a user. Here, the input is a lower triangular matrix and the user may enter the 'x' character which has to be replaced with `INT_MAX`.
The below program is not working correctly as the output is not matching the expected one.

```
#include <limits.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int read_int() {
    char input[30] = {0};
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(input) - 1; i++){
        char c = (char)getc(stdin);
        if (c == 'x' || c == 'X')
            return INT_MAX;

        if (c < '0' || '9' < c){
            if (i == 0) continue;
            input[i] = 0;
            return atoi(input);
        }
        input[i] = c;
    }
    input[29] = 0;
    return atoi(input);
}

int main() { 
    int N = read_int();
    int matrix[N][N];
    memset(matrix, 0, N * N * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j){
            int distance = read_int();
            matrix[i][j] = distance;
            matrix[j][i] = distance;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0; 
}
```

For input:

```
3
x 2
x x 2
```

The Above program prints:

```
3           2147483647  2147483647
2147483647  32          2147483647
2147483647  2147483647  32
```

which is not expected
It should be

```
3           2147483647  2147483647
2147483647  2            2147483647
2147483647  2147483647  2
```

Update: The answers below, doesn't work for all case [except accepted one]

One such case is -

```
5
10
50 20
30 5 30
100 20 50 40
10 x x 10 50
```

it just keeps on taking input

Comment: It's strange that you claim none of the current answers work for you, because I took your code just now, edited in my suggested changes, and it works just fine with this input...  exactly as I expected -- see a [live demo](https://ideone.com/VBb9LG).  I notice that you've modified the `main` to now read a value indicating the number of rows, so you should ensure you're actually providing that extra value as part of your input.  Specifically, your original 3-line input is now out of date because it requires an extra `3` at the beginning.  If omitted then yeah it's probably expecting more input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for skipping whitespace is broken because when you eventually assign a character after skipping position 0, you will always be writing a "wanted" character at position `i`.  That means anything already in position 0 remains.

In your case, it's undefined behavior because `input[0]` was originally filled with 3 on the first input where no whitespace was skipped, but in subsequent calls to your function it is uninitialized.  You then go on to write a 2 into `input[1]` and thus by pure chance (your array from previous calls has not been overwritten on the stack and the stack is the same), you end up with the string "32" sitting in `input`.

What you need to do is have some way to count the actual required characters so that you write them into the array at the correct position.  One naive approach would be:

```
int pos = 0;

for(...) {
    // other logic...

    // Actually write a character we want
    input[pos++] = c;
}
```

Another way that is more like how integer input works is:

```
int c;
int pos = 0;
while(pos < sizeof(input) - 1 && (c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == 'x' || c == 'X')
        return INT_MAX;
    else if (pos == 0 && isspace(c))
        continue;
    else if (!isdigit(c) && !(pos == 0 && (c == '-' || c == '+')))
        break;
    input[pos++] = c;
}
input[pos] = '\0';
return atoi(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this part of the loop:

```
    if (c < '0' || '9' < c){
        if (i == 0) continue;
        input[i] = 0;
        return atoi(input);
    }
```

If you have entered `3`<kbd>enter</kbd>`x 2` as your input, then the `3` gets read successfully, and the the `x` gets returned as `INT_MAX` as intended, but in the next call to `read_int`, the next character in the input sequence is a space (i.e. `c == ' '`), and therefore it branches here. Since `i == 0` at this point, the loop continues, which means `i` is incremented to 1, but this also means that `input[0]` is never changed. Most likely, `input[0]` contains the same value from the previous call to `read_int` (3), but in any case, it's undefined behaviour.

As a quick alternative, you can simply change this condition to:

```
if (c != ' ' && (c < '0' || '9' < c)){
```

This will mean `input[0]` will be set to a space character, which `atoi` will ignore.

An alternative solution could be to read in an entire line at once and tokenise the line.